# How can I add totals to the top of each bar in a percentage bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, geom-bar, geom-text

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)
totals <- pasc_both %>%
    group_by(event_number) %>%
    summarize(total = length(severity_fatigue))

sfatigue_plot <- ggplot(pasc_both, 
       aes(x = factor(event_number,
                      levels = c("0", "1", "2","3", "4", "5", 
                                "6", "7", 
                                "8", "9", "10", "12", "14")),
           fill = factor(severity_fatigue, 
                         levels = c("None", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))),
       label = ) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), 
                     label = percent) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  labs(y = "Percent", 
       fill = "Symptom Severity",
       x = "Week",
       title = "Fatigue") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(data = totals,
                aes(y = 100,
                    x = event_number,
                    label = total),
                size = 7,
                position = position_fill(vjust = 1.02))
```

I receive the following error when running the code:
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `factor()`:
! object 'severity_fatigue' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Try adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to your `geom_text` call.

Comment: ^ the reason you're getting an error is that your top-level `ggplot(aes()` call says that every layer should look at x based on event_number and fill based on severity_fatigue. Your text layer specifies a y and label mapping, and overrides the x mapping with event_number, but it can't find severity_fatigue in the `totals` data.